# Cyborg texturing in Cinema 4d

Tags: animation, texture, cinema4d

I'm doing project about Cyborgs and I saw this animation in instagram. How do you think This texture is applied and the movement of texture is made?

https://www.instagram.com/p/BVskoXTAkCC/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The texture doesn't move.

The degree of either normal or displacement applied to the mesh changes as a gradient over time, then eases back. This is... not very complicated, especially in comparison to much of this artist's other work, some of which is quite stunning.

Seeing as you know exactly who did it, you could ask how they assembled it.

hope this helps.